# Cómo hacer Foreach en directorios ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#

Estoy queriendo recorrer varias carpetas con varias `foreach`, ya que cada carpeta o tiene subcarpetas o tiene archivos.

La carpetas que quiero recorrer son Fechas, por lo que quiero recorrer en un año, las carpetas de los meses, y las carpetas de los días, y dentro de los días tengo archivos `.jpg`. Es asi: wwwroot\imágenes[año][mes][dia][imagen.jpg]

Como ejemplo de directorio, es asi: wwwroot\imagenes\2022\08\09\vehiculo.jpg

El problema que estoy teniendo es que me recorre bien la primera vez, es decir pasa por el primer mes, pasa por el día y recupera las imágenes, pero luego el `foreach` se repite y pasa por el mismo mes y por el mismo día, multiplicándome las imágenes. ¿Cómo puedo resolverlo?

Asi estoy haciendo los `foreach`

```
 dir = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                fechaAMD = dir.Split("/");
                listaPedidos = new List<PedidoViewModel>();
                
                //\imagenes\2022\08\09\...
                imagenes = Directory.GetFiles(@"wwwroot\imagenes\" + fechaAMD[0] + @"\" + fechaAMD[1] + @"\" + fechaAMD[2] + @"\", "*.jpg");

                // \imagenes\2022\08\..               
                carpetaDia = Directory.GetDirectories(@"wwwroot\imagenes\" + fechaAMD[0] + @"\" + fechaAMD[1] + @"\");
                
                // \imagenes\2022\..
                carpetaMes = Directory.GetDirectories(@"wwwroot\imagenes\" + fechaAMD[0] + @"\" );

                // \imagenes\..
                carpetaAnio = Directory.GetDirectories(@"wwwroot\imagenes\");

                foreach(var carAnio in carpetaAnio)
                {
                    foreach (var carMes in carpetaMes)
                    {
                        foreach (var carDia in carpetaDia)
                        {
                            foreach (var img in imagenes)
                            {
                                rutaSplit = img.Split("\\");
                                rutaImagen = img.Split("wwwroot");
                                imagenRecuperada = rutaSplit[5].Split("_");

                                if (identi != "" && identi == imagenRecuperada[0])
                                {
                                    pedido = new PedidoViewModel();
                                    pedido.setNumeroPedido(identi);
                                    pedido.setNumeroEntrega(imagenRecuperada[1]);
                                    pedido.setNumeroRemito(imagenRecuperada[2]);
                                    pedido.setimagenes(rutaImagen[1]);
                                    pedido.setMonto("$11111");
                                    listaPedidos.Add(pedido);
                                }
                            }                            
                        }
                    }
                }                

                return listaPedidos;
```

Debuggeando vi que carpetaMes sí está cambiando pero carpetaDia no
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo no se va a repetir si ese índice es el mismo para todo? Estás definiendo todo desde fuera de la parte dinámica, si tienes el Foreach en anios, dentro de cada iteración, va nuevamente la definición del recorrido de los meses, dentro de cada mes, va nuevamente la definición del recorrido de los días.

Comment: no te serviria mejor un metodo recursivo?

Comment: los dos comentarios son tu solucion....

Comment: No lo hice recursivo ya que tengo entendido de que produzca excepcion de desbordamiento de la pila si el árbol de directorios es grande y cuenta con muchos elementos anidados. Por ahi al principio funciona perfectamente, pero luego a medida que se vaya usando la aplicación voy a tener muchisimos archivos.

Comment: No. aca no tenes problemas con recursividad, porque segun lo que decis, vas a entrar como mucho a algo de profundidad 4... un año, un mes, un dia... y no vas a ir mas alla... asi que no, no tendrias problemas de recursividad....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final siguiendo lo que dijo @fredyfx, Estaba usando la misma ruta una y otra vez, por lo que le di nuevo directorios en cada `foreach`, o al menos por ahora funciona perfectamente.

```
foreach(var carAnio in carpetaAnio)
                {
                    carpetaMes = Directory.GetDirectories(carAnio);
                    foreach (var carMes in carpetaMes)
                    {
                        carpetaDia = Directory.GetDirectories(carMes);
                        foreach (var carDia in carpetaDia)
                        {
                            imagenes = Directory.GetFiles(carDia);
                            foreach (var img in imagenes)
                            {
                                rutaSplit = img.Split("\\");
                                rutaImagen = img.Split("wwwroot");
                                imagenRecuperada = rutaSplit[5].Split("_");

                                if (identi == imagenRecuperada[0])
                                {
                                    pedido = new PedidoViewModel();
                                    pedido.setNumeroPedido(identi);
                                    pedido.setNumeroEntrega(imagenRecuperada[1]);
                                    pedido.setNumeroRemito(imagenRecuperada[2]);
                                    pedido.setimagenes(rutaImagen[1]);
                                    pedido.setMonto("$11111");
                                    listaPedidos.Add(pedido);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```